# Image Storage Spring Data + SQLite database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to store an image blob in a SQLite database using Spring Data Entity and Spring Data Rest ( with @RepositoryRestResource annotated repository )
my SQLiteDialect:

```
public SQLiteDialect() {
    ......
    registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
    registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
    registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
    // registerColumnType(Types.NULL, "null");
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
    registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
    registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");
```

.....
and in  my Entity I have a field image  :

```
@Lob
@Size(max = 2000000000)
private byte[] image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using base64 encoded image persisted as string.